# How to return Java 'java.time.Instant' property as json value in Restful API body response?

Tags: java, spring, rest, java.time.instant

I have a Spring Boot restful API service that returns a Java object in its response which is translated into json.

One of the Java object properties is a 'Java.time.Instant'.  How should I translate this for the json object being returned?

### update

I've tried using @JsonFormat but this doesn't work...

The Java object being returned has an 'Instant' property...

```
 @JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",timezone = "UTC")
 public Instant getRequested() {
     return Requested;
}
```

This is coming back in the json response body as...

```
"requested": {
    "epochSecond": 1499342121,
    "nano": 868000000
},
```

I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4

The controller method is...

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method= RequestMethod.POST)
public AcceptedAccountRequest newRequest(@RequestBody NewAccountRequest aRequest) {
AcceptedAccountRequest anAcceptedRequest = createAccepted(aRequest);
return anAcceptedRequest;
}
```

Comment: You can use [`.toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) which gets a long value. Then returning it back to Instant is more easier with `.ofEpochMilli`

Comment: Reading further on this,  the general sentiment seems to be to have all json timestamp properties returned using the 8601 format.  Is use of the '@jsonformat' annotation the right way to serve this?

Comment: `java.time.Instant` has ISO-8601 as string representation, a swift look into the [API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toString--) also would've revealed this - so as long as you're **not** using some weird, reflection-based serialization you're good to go. Please use google.

Comment: I've tried adding @JsonFormat but the json being generated doesn't recognise ths...

Answer (score 4):

Solved it...   I was mising theh jsr310 maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

On clarification... if I want all Instant properties to be returned in json as UTC should i use the following format instruction, or is there another better way of doing this...

```
@JsonFormat(shape=JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",timezone = "UTC")
```

Comment: There is a better way - add the following to your application.properties: `spring.jackson.serialization.write_dates_as_timestamps=false`

Answer (score 4):

1. pom.xml add

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. application.properties add

   ```
   spring.jackson.serialization.write-dates-as-timestamps=false
   ```

link https://codeboje.de/jackson-java-8-datetime-handling/

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `java.time.Instant` to their representation using `.toString()`
If you are using Spring, you might have to add @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME) to your RestMethod in order to make sure it is converted correctly

Comment: I can't get this to work. Whatever annotation I put in the json being returned comes across as ...     "validUntil": {
        "epochSecond": 1499772556,
        "nano": 656000000
    }   .

Comment: I'm using Spring Boot 1.5.4